# Value of Indefinite Integralsl involving Trigonometric function

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Finding $\displaystyle \int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{\bigg(\sin^{2009}x+\cos^{2009} x\bigg)^2}\cdot (\sin^{2008}(2x))dx$

Try: $$\int \frac{\ln(\cot x)}{\bigg(1+\tan^{2009}(x)\bigg)^2}\cdot \tan^{2008}(x)\cdot \sec^{2010}(x)dx$$

Now substuting $\tan^{2009} x=t$ and $\displaystyle \tan^{2008}(x)\cdot \sec^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{2009}dt$

So $$ -\frac{1}{(2009)^2}\int\frac{\ln(t)}{(1+t)^2}\cdot (1+t^{\frac{2}{2009}})^{1005}dt$$

Could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me source of this problem, thank

Comment: Might be easier if you put n instead of 2009.

Comment: Actually original question was Finding $\displaystyle \int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{\bigg(\sin^{2009}x+\cos^{2009} x\bigg)^2}\cdot (\sin^{2008}(2x))dx$extremelly sorry for that.

Comment: Do you wish to change original question or keep it in original form? Math love has edited and even answered with edited question. Edited question can be said to be much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$, we have
$$\begin{align}&\int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{(\sin^{n+1}x+\cos^{n+1} x)^2}\cdot (\sin^{n}(2x))\ \mathrm dx\\\\&=\int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{(\sin^{n+1}x+\cos^{n+1} x)^2}\cdot 2^n\sin^nx\cos^nx\ \mathrm dx\\\\&=-2^n\int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{(\sin^{n+1}x+\cos^{n+1} x)^2}\cdot \sin^{2n+2}x\cdot\frac{-\cot^nx}{\sin^2x}\ \mathrm dx\\\\&=-2^n\int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{(1+\cot^{n+1} x)^2}\cdot\frac{-\cot^nx}{\sin^2x}\ \mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Let $s=1+\cot^{n+1}x$. Then, since $\frac{\mathrm ds}{n+1}=\frac{-\cot^nx}{\sin^2x}\ \mathrm dx$, we get

$$\begin{align}&-2^n\int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{(1+\cot^{n+1} x)^2}\cdot\frac{-\cot^nx}{\sin^2x}\ \mathrm dx\\\\&=-2^n\int\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\ln(s-1)}{s^2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm ds}{n+1}\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2}\int (s^{-1})'\ln(s-1)\ \mathrm ds\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2}\left(s^{-1}\ln(s-1)-\int\frac{1}{s(s-1)}\ \mathrm ds\right)\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2}\left(s^{-1}\ln(s-1)+\int\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s-1}\right)\ \mathrm ds\right)\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2}\left(s^{-1}\ln(s-1)+\ln s-\ln(s-1)\right)+\mathrm C\\\\&=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2}\left(\frac{\ln(\cot^{n+1}x)}{1+\cot^{n+1}x}+\ln(1+\cot^{n+1}x)-\ln(\cot^{n+1}x)\right)+\mathrm C\end{align}$$

Therefore, for $n=2008$, we have
$$\int\frac{\ln(\cot x)}{(\sin^{2009}x+\cos^{2009} x)^2}\cdot (\sin^{2008}(2x))\ \mathrm dx$$$$=\frac{2^{2008}}{2009^2}\left(\frac{\ln(\cot^{2009}x)}{1+\cot^{2009}x}+\ln(1+\cot^{2009}x)-\ln(\cot^{2009}x)\right)+\mathrm C$$